# Determine UserID if Application Role used

Tags: sql-server, winforms

My application will be implemented using VB.NET connecting to SQL Server 2008 R2.

I am considering using an Application Role for the connection, but I need to know the user's ID to limit which data they can view/update.

Is this possible if I use an Application Role?

Comment: You will need to pass the User's ID as a parameter every time you send a query/command to the DB.

Comment: Great, thank you for the suggestion. I can allow the Application Role to access the SystemUser table to get the UserID and go from there. Can you post as an answer so it can be marked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server can't access your Application Roles, but you can use them to populate a parameter which you can pass to SQL Server in each query/command.